# Replace only the path of image usig preg_replace in php

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I am using preg_replace to alter the image path only except image name like:

```
<img src="http://www.ByPasspublishing.com/uploadedImages/TinyUploadedImage/SOC_Aggression_Define_Fig Territorial Aggression.jpg" />
```

to

Below is the code I have tried but it replace the total path. Please help me to solve this problem:

```
$html = preg_replace('/<img([^>]+)src="([^"]+)"/i','<img\\1src="newfolder"',$slonodes[0]->SLO_content);
```

Another thing is that `$slonodes[0]->SLO_content` returns an HTML content within which I have to find the image and replace the path of that image so the path will not be same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are missing ending quote from SRC attribute. Img tag must belike: <img src="source/to/image.jpg" title="some title if you like" alt="alternative content, if image wasn't found" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use an HTML Parser for this task, DOMDocument in particular:

```
$html = '<img src="http://www.ByPasspublishing.com/uploadedImages/TinyUploadedImage/SOC_Aggression_Define_Fig Territorial Aggression.jpg" />';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();

$img = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0);
$new_src = 'newfolder/' . basename($img->getAttribute('src'));
$img->setAttribute('src', $new_src);
echo $dom->saveHTML($img);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use regex? O.o

You can do something like this:

```
$path = "http://www.ByPasspublishing.com/uploadedImages/TinyUploadedImage/SOC_Aggression_Define_Fig Territorial Aggression.jpg";
$pathNew = "newfolder/".substr(strrchr($path, "/"), 1);
print $pathNew;
```

I cut on the last "/" char and then concatenate Strings and chars to obtain your desired output.

Comment: I know but "http://www.ByPasspublishing.com/uploadedImages/TinyUploadedImage" this path will not be static it will change .

Comment: My code cut everything until last "/", is this different? I replyed to your question, you haven't talked about limitations.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have edited my question, please check could you help me in that.

Comment: sorry but '$slonodes[0]->SLO_content' what contains? Oo

Comment: $slonodes[0]->SLO_content' this is a variable where the dynamic content come.

Comment: okay, and this content is the path of the image + image name?